# keras Deep Learning Slowness - Example IMDB dataset from Deep Learning with Python Chollet

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am having an issue with keras leading to my processor seemingly getting bogged down while working through examples.

In the IMDB data set for instance (exercise 3.4.1 in Deep Learning with Python by Chollet if anyone knows the book), running the script:

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import imdb    
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = 
    imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
```

Produces an output looking something like:

```
[=====>...] - ETA: 59s✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓16105472/17464789
```

That updates increasingly slowly as the numbers get larger and move toward completion.

I'm assuming my installation of keras/Tensorflow/CUDA/cuDNN is to blame, but curious if you know of anything obvious that would solve the issue.

Running Ubuntu Linux, NVIDIA GTX 1080, Keras/Tensorflow (GPU)/CUDA,cuDNN (maybe, assuming I installed everything correctly which is probably not accurate).

Thanks!

Comment: Have your tried to increase num_words?

Comment: I tried to decrease num_words, but not to increase? The example I'm following uses 10,000.

Comment: num_words is probably the size that it will try to fit in a dataload. You should increase/decrease based on memory usage you check with `nvidia-smi` cmd.

Answer (score 0):

This progress bar is shown during the first initial download and should not be present on subsequent imports of the data.
There might be several issues that cause this to slow down and/or fail:

- Your internet connection is unstable.
- There is an issue with the serving of the file. Maybe the repository server serves a corrupt file? (You could try to force download from another repository, see [How to setup pip to download from mirror repository by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60814982/how-to-setup-pip-to-download-from-mirror-repository-by-default) )
- Your local disc or or a previously partial download are corrput: You can try to delete a partial download in ~/.keras/datasets/mnist.npz
- Check if your harddisk is full.