# How to setup pip to download from mirror repository by default?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am forced to download python packages from local mirror PyPi repository. I do this by using the `-i` and `--trusted-host` options. Whole installation command looks like this:

```
pip install -i https://sampleurl.com/pypi-remote/simple --trusted-host sample.host.com package_name
```

Having to type in that options each time is kinda annoying though (in reality those are long URL's). I've tried to create `get_package.bat` file (I'm working on Windows 10) with following content:

```
pip install -i https://sampleurl.com/pypi-remote/simple --trusted-host sample.host.com "%1"
```

It works perfectly fine, although when I wanted to execute pip search command, it turned out to be useless since it has hard-coded `install` command and there is no way to use it with `search`.

Is there any way in which I can setup pip to download from mirror repository by default, so that I can execute `pip install package_name` or `pip search package_name` without any additional options?

Eventually I could try making `.bat` file that would take 2 parameters like this:

```
pip %1 -i https://sampleurl.com/pypi-remote/simple --trusted-host sample.host.com "%2"
```

But I wonder if there's more "elegant" way to do this.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

using [pip config](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_config/), on user or global level. I have `/etc/pip.conf` configured like this:

```
[global]
index=https://my-company/nexus/repository/pypi-group/pypi
index-url=https://my-company/nexus/repository/pypi-group/simple
trusted-host=my-company
```

but you can configure this using `pip config` on user or global level, something like:

```
pip config --user set global.index https://my-company/nexus/repository/pypi-group/pypi
pip config --user set global.index-url https://my-company/nexus/repository/pypi-group/simple
pip config --user set global.trusted-host my-company
```

#NOTES

- `--index-url` is used by [pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-0)
- `--index` is used by [pip search](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_search/)

Comment: It works, except on the third line it should be `pip config --user set global.trusted-host my-company` instead of what you wrote (without the equals char).

Comment: as a side note it makes sense to use a https server, most custom pypi implementations provide https as well as http for backwards compatibility, but https provides encrypted communication for authentication etc. @chris-maes I would suggest to adjust this in your answer

Answer (score 37):

Use `pip3 config list -v` to get list of locations where your pip.conf is located. Then go to one of the location(I prefer user) and add your URL.
The file should look like this, if empty then add the lines.

```
[global]
index-url=https://pypi.org/simple
extra-index-url=<your_url>
```

In case if you want pip to look into your URL first then switch the places of url on above options.

```
[global]
index-url=<your_url>
extra-index-url=https://pypi.org/simple
```

Comment: The OP wants to download from his mirror **by default**, `extra-index-url` will still use pypi.org, which is not what he wants.

Comment: that's why i said after the code block "In case if you want pip to look into your URL first then switch the places of url on above options."

Comment: I think you should edit this answer, adding another file example showing what you mean by "switching places" because I'm not sure it is immediately clear to everyone what you're saying.  I had to reread it several times myself.

Answer (score 6):

You could also add the `-i` and `--trusted-host` options to your `requirements.txt` like this:

```
-i https://sampleurl.com/pypi-remote/simple --trusted-host sample.host.com
numpy==1.23.4
pandas==1.5.1
```

And then, just do:

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

which gives:

```
Looking in indexes: https://sampleurl.com/pypi-remote/simple
Collecting numpy==1.23.4
  Downloading numpy-1.23.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.1 MB)
...
```

---

I found this solution to work well in case you don't necessary want to create a `pip.conf` file (for example, in CIs).

Comment: Nice solution, but the problem is that it will try downloading all packages from that index.

Comment: @Charalamm - which is exactly what the OP question asked how to do.