# pip - use project folder as installation source

Tags: python, pip

I would like to configure `pip` to use a custom search path to install packages from a local folder, which are not hosted on PyPI. The goal is to be able to run

```sh
$ pip install --user my_non_published_package
```

And have it install said package from `/home/myuser/projects/my_non_published_package`.

I know that I can explicitely install it using

```sh
$ pip install --user /home/myuser/projects/my_non_published_package
```

but this is *not* what I want. I want pip to transparently resolve potential depencies of other packages and install them from `/home/myuser/projects/<package>` iff they are not hosted on PyPI. So, if I have a project `foo` having a `setup.py` containing

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        bar,
        ...
    ],
    ...
)
```

And package `bar` is not on PyPI, I want pip to install it from `/home/myuser/projects/bar` automatically.

**Update**
I found some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668295/how-to-include-and-install-local-dependencies-in-setup-py-in-python), but the proposed solution does not work.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""Setup configuration."""

from pathlib import Path

from setuptools import setup


def local_pkg(name: str) -> str:
    """Returns a path to a local package."""
    return f'{name} @ file://{Path.cwd().parent / name}'

setup(
    name='openimmodb',
    use_scm_version={
        "local_scheme": "node-and-timestamp"
    },
    setup_requires=['setuptools_scm'],
    author='HOMEINFO - Digitale Informationssysteme GmbH',
    author_email='<info at homeinfo dot de>',
    maintainer='Richard Neumann',
    maintainer_email='<r dot neumann at homeinfo period de>',
    install_requires=[
        local_pkg('filedb'),
        local_pkg('mdb'),
        local_pkg('openimmo'),
        local_pkg('openimmolib'),
        'peewee',
        local_pkg('peeweeplus'),
        'pyxb',
        local_pkg('timelib'),
        local_pkg('xmldom')
    ],
    packages=[
        'openimmodb',
        'openimmodb.dom',
        'openimmodb.dom.ausstattung',
        'openimmodb.json',
        'openimmodb.json.ausstattung',
        'openimmodb.json.barrier_freeness',
        'openimmodb.json.flaechen',
        'openimmodb.json.immobilie',
        'openimmodb.json.preise',
        'openimmodb.mixins',
        'openimmodb.orm'
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'oidbctl = openimmodb.oidbctl:main'
        ]
    },
    description='Relational OpenImmo database'
)
```

Results in:

```sh
...
Processing dependencies for openimmodb==0.1.dev987+g199a834.d20220110094301
Searching for xmldom@ file:///home/neumann/Projekte/xmldom
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/xmldom/
Couldn't find index page for 'xmldom' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
```

Even though it is there:

```sh
 $ ls /home/neumann/Projekte/xmldom
LICENSE  Makefile  README.md  setup.py  venv  xmldom.egg-info  xmldom.py
```

Same with additional `localhost`:

```sh
Searching for xmldom@ file://localhost/home/neumann/Projekte/xmldom
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/xmldom/
Couldn't find index page for 'xmldom' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
```

And with `#egg=`

```sh
Processing dependencies for openimmodb==0.1.dev987+g199a834.d20220110095236
Searching for xmldom@ file://localhost/home/neumann/Projekte/xmldom#egg=xmldom
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/xmldom/
Couldn't find index page for 'xmldom' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
```

With the absolute path in `install_requires` I get:

```sh
$ python setup.py install
error in openimmodb setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Parse error at "'/home/ne'": Expected W:(abcd...)
```

Comment: So your problem is that the package `bar` it's your private project and pip cannot find it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup pip to download from mirror repository by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60814982/how-to-setup-pip-to-download-from-mirror-repository-by-default)

Comment: @PaulKocian Exactly. 9769953 No it does not.

Comment: @RichardNeumann, did you try adding the full path instead of just the name? (`file://your/path/to/package`)